# How linux paging and segmenting could be combined?

Tags: linux, memory

I am studying Linux / OS fundamentals and recently have got familiar with an idea of memory paging and segmentation.

AFIK segmentation does not allow split segments - thus they are either entirely in memory or in swap, but never split by smaller pieces.

From the other hand pages allow to split memory on smaller independent blocks.

Now, though, I probably understand every concept separately, I can't get my head around how one can combine two approaches.

Some tutorial say that segmentation could be used *together* with paging, where segments get split by pages, however this *seems* to contradict the very idea of indivisible segments ...

Comment: "AFIK segmentation does not allow split segments - thus they are either entirely in memory or in swap, but never split by smaller pieces." This is not true. They're split into pages, and paging deals with this level.

Comment: This is a programming site, it's not for questions about OS design. If you want to ask about OS fundamentals in general, [cs.se] is probably a better place. If you want to ask specifically about Linux, [linux.se] is the place.